# Best practice for three environment setup - to avoid pushing things live when not ready yet

Tags: git, branch

I am fairly new with git, and am not quite sure what is the best way to go about doing what I need to do.

So the setup I have is this: I have my localhost where I do the work, then I have a test environment where the client can test out new functionality, then I have the production environment.

The production environment has just recently gone live and until then I was pushing everything to the live and test servers as soon as it was working (simply tested by me) which was ok since the system wasn't 100% live yet. Now the client wants me to push everything to the test server and allow them to test it and let me know which parts are ready to go live and which parts still need work. What is the best way to handle this without accidentally pushing things to the live server that are not ready yet but have already been pushed to the test server.

I thought I could just create branches while I was working on things and when I had it working merge it into the testing branch and push it to the test server, and remove the feature branch, but then I seem to have to push it all to the production branch all at once instead of picking which features I want and only pushing those live.

Here are the options I can think of:

Option 1 - 
Create a new branch for each and every bug fix and feature request and merge them to the testing branch for testing and then merge them individually with the production branch after each has been tested.

Option 2 - 
Tell the client that I have to push a large batch of updates at once not just one or two as they pick and choose. (obviously not the best option)

The problem I have with option 1 is that, I assume I would have to create each branch off the master or production branch and that some fixes or features might be dependent upon other things that have already been fixed in dev branch but have not pushed to production yet.

I'm hoping that I am missing some functionality of git that will help out in situations like this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is something a lot of people swear by. I would recommend looking at that.

My own personal Git workflow is something like this.

#### All new work goes into its own branch, based off master

For this, I use `git checkout -b my-new-branch`. If `master` changes while I'm developing, then I can switch back there -- `git stash` (if I have any changes), then `git checkout master` -- then `git pull --rebase master` to get those latest changes. Once I've got the latest changes for `master`, then I switch back to the other branch `git checkout -` and then `git rebase master`.

#### Work that is based off an existing non-master branch, is based off that branch

Similar to the above, but the `git checkout -b` is ran on the non-master branch.

Those "rules" pretty much get me through every day. As for your `testing` branch, I would call it something like `staging` (as in "a staging area") and then *merge* (not rebase) branches into that as I need to using `git merge <branch name>`. Then `staging` would have the correct things.

When you want to add that to production, you can merge the branch there too: `git merge <branch name>`. I would not advise to rebase on `staging` because that would complicate things, and there really shouldn't be any extra changes applied to staging. Any work goes on a branch, which is then merged into `staging`, verified to be working, then merged into `production`.